# How do I set Encoding on AlternateView

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm creating a mailBody via

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fooFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    streamWriter.Write(fooMessage);
}
```

now i'm consuming this file with

```
var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
{
    From = fooSender,
    To =
    {
        fooRecipient
    },
    Subject = fooSubject,
    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
// fooMediaType can be
// - System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html
// - System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain
var alternateView = new System.Net.Mail.AlternateView(fooFileName, fooMediaType);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);
```

If I'm using non-umlauts, everything works fine, but as soon as I'm using umlauts in my `alternateView`, they get broken.

So how can I set some sort of encoding on the alternateView that everything is working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 var alternateView = new AlternateView(fooFileName, fooMediaType)
 {
      ContentType =
      {
           CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
      }
 };
```

Comment: Very helpful! It might be better to use `Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName` because the charset parameter will be added to the Content-Type header. In this case `Encoding.UTF8.WebName` and `Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName` both return the same value `utf-8` so it does not really matter.