# AlternateView and čćžšđ when sending mail by C#

Tags: c#

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(email.From,
                                                      email.To,
                                                      email.Subject,
                                                      email.Body);

                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

                string body = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">";
                body += "<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">";
                body += "</HEAD><BODY><DIV>";
                body += email.Body.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
                body += "</DIV></BODY></HTML>";

AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Regex.Replace(email.Body, @"<(.|\n)*?", string.Empty), null, "text/plain");
                message.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);

ContentType mimeType = new ContentType("text/html");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(email.Body, mimeType);
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

where email.Body and email.Subject is for example "čžćšđščžčžčšđš"

and when i get mail, Subject is ok but body is corrupted like ÄÅ¾Å¡Ä‘

Problem is in AlternateView.

here:

```
ContentType mimeType = new ContentType("text/html");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(email.Body, mimeType);
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following question

- [How do I set Encoding on AlternateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185371/howto-set-encoding-on-alternateview)

the answer is to set the content type of the alternate view appropriately. You are passing `null` as the encoding, consider passing UTF-8 instead:

```
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
    Regex.Replace(email.Body, @"<(.|\n)*?", string.Empty), 
    Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using null for AlternateView encoding in constructor, replace it with Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
Update:
You've updated your question before it was using null in constructor, anyway there is constructor with encoding parameter.