# Incorrect encoding in e-mails sent with System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

When receiving e-mails sent with `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` some recipients seem to have encoding issues with the e-mail. For example charachter **ä** is displayed as **Ã¤**. I have set encoding properties:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
...
msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
msg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

What else can I do?

**Update:**

If I use the `Body` property the e-mail is displayed correctly, but when I use the `AlternateViews` property the e-mail is displayed incorrectly.

Complete code:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("some.host.com");
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("someone@host.com");
msg.From = new MailAddress("name@host.com", "Name Name");
msg.Subject = "Test";

//Displays as ä
//msg.Body = "ä";

// Displays as Ã¤
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("ä", new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

When sending to Gmail the e-mail is displayed correctly, but when sending to an Exchange server the e-mail is displayed incorrectly. I have tested in .NET 3.5 and 4.5.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Could you add your complete mailing code so I can try to recreate this?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185371/howto-set-encoding-on-alternateview?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the content type to the Alternative View:

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("ä", new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
htmlView.ContentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
```

Comment: Don't know if this relates to the OP, but a close look at the raw message content was enough for me to understand why this answer makes sense. My message body text, after all, was encoded as an AlternateView, so setting BodyEncoding DOES its job, but it's a textless body: you have no text in body, but in an AlternateView.

Comment: mail.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "content=text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\""); This should work too without alternateview (setting ecoding with meta tag in html's body header doesn't work, coz  MailMessage class removes meta tags from body).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the BodyEncoding and SubjectEncoding affects reading of messages in any way - it applies to when you send messages and sets the text encoding for the messages and headers when messages are sent.

SmtpClient will read the content-type and charset encoding from messages sent and decode the content of the message and subject according to the encoding it finds in the headers.

If your message is not getting decoded, it seems that the messages are possibly not encoded correctly (or potentially double encoded UTF-8 encoded string getting encoded again by a message encoder), the request headers on the message don't properly match the actual encoding of the message or a charset format that isn't supported in .NET is used.

The only way to know though is to look at the actual raw request trace of a message that fails to see what's actually getting sent.

You might want to set up System.NET tracing for email messages (see http://codepaste.net/j52ktp) or else monitor the TCP/IP stream with something like Wireshark to see what's actually going over the wire and what the headers are instructing the client to do with the data.

FWIW, there's no reason if a message is properly UTF-8 encoded for SmtpClient to not read these messages correctly.